# Program prints weird symbols to output file C++

Tags: c++, file, output, symbols

Okay so this is a small piece of an incomplete program. The program reads an input file, does some calculations and prints to an output file, but instead weird symbols are in the output file.

```
void printRecord (char name[20], char Id[20], ostream& outfile)
{
outfile <<  name <<  Id  << endl;
}

int main()
{
ofstream outfile;
ifstream infile; 


char file_nameI[21], file_nameO[21], name[20], Id[8];

float  hworkgrade, grade1;
int deductions;

cout << "Please enter name of input file:  ";
cin >> file_nameI;
infile.open(file_nameI);
if ( !infile)
{
  cout << "Could not open input file \n";
  return 0;
}

cout << "Please enter name of output file:  ";
cin >> file_nameO;
outfile.open(file_nameO);
if ( !outfile)
{
  cout << "Could not open output file \n";
  return 0;
}

do
{
  infile >> name >> Id;
  cout<< name << Id;
  hworkgrade = CalHworkGrade(grade1, infile);
  printRecord(name, Id, outfile);
}
while(!infile.eof());

return 0;
}
```

This is what was in the output file

Ф,ью\XаѓФ,ью

Comment: This usually is caused by printing variables that are not initialized.

Comment: you are right. Now I have to figure out why the program isn't pulling the new information from the input file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

program is not pulling info from input file. If i set the variable to hello they are not overwritten with the new info and the program prints hello

```
char file_nameI[21], file_nameO[21], name[20] = hello , Id[8]  = hello;
```